# Getting NSDate from NSString using NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

In my projet I am getting date value in the below format,

```
NSString* str = @"04-10-2011 20:00:00";
```

Then I am trying to convert it to date

```
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];  
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:str];
```

It is getting `nil`. Am I giving wrong date format? Can any one let me know?

Comment: Everything is OK with your code. It is returning date as '2011-04-10 14:30:00 +0000'

Comment: @DipakSonara check your time in console. It does not match

Comment: But everything is perfect in your code .and not get nil .

Comment: you have to use `df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];` to get the exact date. Your code is in working state

Comment: @Morpheus : Yes sir.!! You are right. I just argued about returning 'nil'

Comment: Sorry one thing i didnt mentioned it is working fine in Simulator but in Device I am getting nil

Comment: Morpheus, I did by adding the Locale I observed some, I went to settings---General--Time&Date there the "24Hrs" is Off then i set as On, Then i tested i got the value, Then turn it off and run the App It is giving me nil, I never faced this scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems pretty, try to use `timezone` property of `dateformatter` to get the exact date

```
NSString* str = @"04-10-2011 20:00:00";
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[df setLocale:locale];
[df setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:str];


NSLog(@"Date is %@", date);
```

Comment: Sorry one thing i didnt mentioned it is working fine in Simulator but in Device I am getting nil

Comment: Edited the answer, now check

Answer (score 1):

```
[df setDateFormat:@"mm-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
```

Comment: `MM` should always be capitalize

Comment: Earlier I used the same Format @"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss" later i changed